# How to interpret K-Means clusters

Tags: java, apache-spark, k-means

I have written code in java using Apache Spark for K-Means clustering.
I want to analyze network data. I created K-Means model using some training data. k=5 and iteration=50.

Now I want detect anomaly record using distance of a record from the center of the cluster. If it is far from the center then it is an anomaly record.

Also I want to find out what type of data each cluster stores. To give an example--- in case of Movie clustering, detecting cluster having common genre or theme among the movies in the cluster

I am having trouble to interpret clusters. I am using one bad record and one good record for prediction but at times both good and bad records fall in same cluster.

Bad record means URI field of that field containing value something like HelloWorld/../../WEB-INF/web.xml.

I get array of all cluster centers from K-Means model. There is no api to get cluster center of a particular cluster. I am calculating distance of a input vector/record from all clusters but I am not able to get cluster center of a specific cluster or where that record is present.

Here is my code,

```
KMeansModel model = KMeans.train(trainingData.rdd(), numClusters,
                numIterations);
```

In separate file,

```
model.save(sparkContext, KM_MODEL_PATH);
Vector[] clusterCenters = model.clusterCenters();

//Input for prediction is <Vector> testData


//Predict data
System.out.println("Test Data cluster ----- "
        + model.predict(vector) + " k ->> " + model.k());

//Calculate distance of a input record from each cluster center
for (Vector clusterCenter : clusterCenters) {
    System.out.println(" Distance "
            + computeDistance(clusterCenter.toArray(),
                    vector.toArray()));
}



//Function for computing distance between input record and center of a cluster
public double computeDistance(double[] clusterCenters, double[] vector) {
        org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector dV1 = new org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector(
                clusterCenters);
        org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector dV2 = new org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector(
                vector);

        return org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.sqdist(dV1, dV2);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand nor what you are doing nor what is your question.

Comment: could you please add some more info to your post?

Comment: Updated original post